# Good notation for defining defining elementary functions from vector functions.

Tags: functions, notation

Let's say we have a function $f:A^c\to B^c$ such that for any $\vec{u} = (u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_c)\in A^c$, any $i,j \leq c$, $u_i = u_j$ iff $f(\vec{u})_i = f(\vec{u})_i$. Then for each $\vec{u} \in A^c$ we can define a partial bijection $g_\vec{u}:A\hookrightarrow B$ with pre-image $\tilde{u}$ such that $g_\vec{u}(u_i) = f(\vec{u})_i$. What then would be good notation to denote this $g_\vec{u}$ using only $f$ and $\vec{u}$?